# How to make an optional root state in angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-routing

i need to do an optional prefix indicating on the language.
So you can go to

***random-domain.com/***

the default language will be selected(en)

and if you with selected language

***random-domain.com/ru***

language will be selected - ru

And this should apply to nested routes

***random-domain.com/some-rand-entity*** and ***random-domain.com/ru/some-rand-entity***

my non-working solution - an example

```
 const app_common: Routes = [ ...];
 export const app_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
    resolve: {
      settings: SettingsStore
    },
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

export const lang_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: ':lang',
    component: HomeComponent,
    resolve: {
      languages: LanguagesStore
    },
    children: app_common,
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
];

export const routes: Routes = [
  ...app_routes,
  ...app_common,
  ...lang_routes,
  ...checkoutRoutes
];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use route parameters for this purpose

```
 export const app_routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', 
    component: HomeComponent,
    resolve: {
      settings: SettingsStore
    },
    pathMatch: 'full',
    children: app_common
  },
  {
    path: ':lang',
    component: HomeComponent,
    resolve: {
      settings: SettingsStore
    },
    children: app_common,
  }
];
```

See also https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-parameters

Comment: it should be optional

Comment: Yes, but what about children?
Withot children that working, but with - no

Comment: I guess you need to add the same children to both routes.

Comment: on both parent states : '' and "lang" i see
Cannot match any routes: ''
or
Cannot match any routes: 'ru'
When i add children

Comment: Try removing `pathMatch: 'full'` on the language route (only keep it at the empty path route).

Answer (score 1):

This is something that should be handled with query parameters

```
url?lang=en
```

not with path parameters

```
url/en  // don't do this
```

To add query params in `routerLinks` you would do

```
<a [routerLink]="..." [queryParams]="{ lang: 'en' }" >link</a>
```

To do with programmatically with `Router`, you would use

```
this.router.navigate(['...'], { queryParams: { lang: 'en' }});
```

To access the query params in a component, the `ActivatedRoute` has a `queryParams` property

```
this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {})
```

We can also preserve the query parameters so we don't need to keep applying them. In the `routerLink` we would do

```
<a [routerLink]="..." [queryParams]="{ lang: 'en' }" preserveQueryParams>link</a>
```

In the `Router` we would do

```
this.router.navigate(['...'], { preserveQueryParams: true});
```

What this does, is that when the current route has query params attached, when we navigate, the params will be automatically attached.

**See Also:**

- [Query Parameters and Fragments](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#query-parameters)
- [Docs for RouterLink](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLink-directive.html)